# How to shift time forward on avd (android emulator) via monkeyrunner script?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, monkeyrunner

I need to change time on my AVD without stopping script.

Task:

1. launch apk
2. take screenshot-1
3. shift time forward on N hours (maybe days)
4. launch browser
5. take screenshot-2
6. Compare two screenshots

How to change time on emulator? can't find any examples with time shifting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
device.shell('date -s YYYYmmdd.HHMMSS`)
```

if you have the right permission.

Comment: Hi. I am new to android emulator. Can you explain a bit in detail this code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with emulator in particular, it's just a shell invoking`date` command.